# How to substract inner text of two nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Would you please help me substract the inner text if 2 nodes.

My xml generated is : (The original XML is until OriIndex)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>0</OriIndex>
    <SortedIndex>0</SortedIndex>
    <Diff>NaN</Diff>
  </Test>
.
.
.
.
.
```

I am not able to get the Diff. For example it should be `<SortedIndex>10</SortedIndex>  - <OriIndex>5</OriIndex> Equals`5 .

My XSLT is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding = "UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="Root">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Test">
      <xsl:sort select="TestPhase" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestFlow" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestParameter" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="Test">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
       <SortedIndex><xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/></SortedIndex>
       <Diff><xsl:value-of select="@SortedIndex - @OriIndex" /></Diff>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help.  Your effort is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Cheers,
newbuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `<Diff><xsl:value-of select="@SortedIndex - @OriIndex" /></Diff>` would compute the difference between attributes of that name, you don't have attributes. If you wanted to compute the difference for child elements you would need `<Diff><xsl:value-of select="SortedIndex - OriIndex" /></Diff>`. However, part of your unclear description sounds as if you don't have that `SortedIndex` in the original input but just create it with XSLT for the result, in that case you would need `<Diff><xsl:value-of select="position() - 1 - OriIndex" /></Diff>`.

Comment: Many thanks To Martin Honnen.  It is working fine.  I actually has missed a logic.  Would you please advice me on how to code this.  I would like to get the difference between current OriIndex inner text and previous OriIndex inner text (just the one before this one).    I put in :       <Diff><xsl:value-of select="OriIndex - OriIndex[position() - 1 ]" /></Diff>,   but it has compile error.  Please help.   Cheers :)